# simple_form - can't generate combined select input

Tags: ruby, simple-form

I have complex form with a lot of controls, and I'm currently using simple_form gem due to its flexibility. But when I wanted to do something more complex I faced to several problems that currently looking obscure for me. I would like to introduce combined collection input, that will render both optgroups and single non-groupped selects. Generated html that I want to achieve should look something like this:

```
<select name="select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Milk</option>
  <optgroup label="Soda">
    <option value="2">Cola</option>
    <option value="3">Fanta</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I've tried to create custom input class, but stucked on implementation details of `input` method, I simply couldn't find out how to generate proper output.

**UPDATE**

Currently quick and dirty implementation for custom input looks something like this, but I don't think that it is a good idea to drop all goodnesses with options that simple_form gives me.

```
class CombinedMultiselectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper

  def input
    out = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new
    option_tags = ungrouped_options.safe_concat(grouped_options)
    out << select_tag(options[:name], option_tags, class: ['select', 'form-control'])
    out
  end

 private

 def ungrouped_options
   # this can be retrieved from general collection like collection[:ungrouped]
   collection = [["Foo", 2], ["Bar", 3]]
   options_for_select(collection)
 end

 def grouped_options
   # and this using collection[:grouped]
   collection = [["Group", [["Foobar", 4]]]]
   grouped_options_for_select(collection)
 end
end
```

Comment: Did you check the Rails helper function [option_groups_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select)?

Comment: yep, but couldn't find a way how to merge it with simple collection_select_input method that is called from builder object.

Comment: The idea was to prepare collection hash with two keys corresponding to ungrouped and grouped collections, and then first render ungrouped and merge output with grouped that will be rendered using `option_groups_from_collection_for_select`.

Comment: Can we see your Collection structure because you can use a combination of `options_for_select` and `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` to achieve this structure but I can't write a proper answer without seeing the collection object e.g. what should be used for `group_method,group_label_method,option_key_method,option_value_method`? As Documented [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select)

Comment: @PlugataryovYura thank you for the additional information I have posted an answer I think will be sufficient for you needs and included `simple_form` integration example (untested)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, either. Currently I'm trying to figure out how to avoid these two includes of ActionView helpers, and get these method from @builder context if is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current design you can combine the `options_for_select` and `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` methods like so.

```
def ungrouped_options
 [["Foo", 2], ["Bar", 3]]
end

def grouped_options
  [["Group", [["Foobar", 4]]]]
end

def your_hash
  {"ungrouped" => ungrouped_options, "grouped" => grouped_options}
end
```

Then in your view something like this should work:

```
<%= content_tag(:select,nil,{multiple: true,name: "select"}) do
  <%= your_hash.each do |k,v| %>
     <% if k == "ungrouped" %>
       <%= options_for_select(v) %> 
     <% else %>
       #this works because:
       # last will be the collection of children for a member
       # first will be the group name
       # last on the child will be the value method 
       # first on the child will be the text displayed
       <%= option_groups_from_collection_for_select(v, :last, :first, :last, :first)  %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will create the following:

```
<select name=\"select\" multiple=\"true\">
    <option value=\"2\">Foo</option>
    <option value=\"3\">Bar</option>
    <optgroup label=\"Group\">
        <option value=\"4\">Foobar</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Obviously this was simplified to show how this could be done but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

You should also be able to wrap this for simple_form although I have not tested it.

```
<%= f.input :some_attribute do %>
  <%= f.select :some_attribute do %>
    <%= your_hash.each do |k,v| %>
      <% if k == "ungrouped" %>
        <%= options_for_select(v) %> 
      <% else %>
        <%= option_groups_from_collection_for_select(v, :last, :first, :last, :first)  %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```